# How do you make it so you can sign in with phone number for app?

Tags: android, ios, database, social-networking, backend

I am making an app and I want to know the overall jist to make it so you can sign in with your phone number. For example, in the app Down to Lunch (an app to invite your friends to get food), once you download it, the first thing you do is sign in with your phone number. From then on, your number is how you are identified in the app. What I want to know is once you submit that number, is it added to a table in a database? Then when a new user registers, that number must go through and check against every number in that table to make sure it is different? If so, wouldn't that take long for a large user base (like a social network) or is that just what databases are capable of doing? (more specifically amazon web services, because I would use their relational database service, im guessing)

Answer (score 2):

You can use library called [**DIGITS**](https://get.digits.com/)  and which is available on **[Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/)**

> Digits lets people create an account or sign into your app using nothing but their phone number on iOS and Android. Built using the same global, reliable infrastructure Twitter uses, Digits will verify the user’s phone number with a simple customizable user interface that easily integrates into your app.

Refer below links:

[DIGITS - Sign in with Phone Number](https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/digits.html) 
[How to configure to app](https://fabric.io/kits/android/digits/summary)

Comment: Great Answer @ Bharat.I too want to use this kind of service in my app.Upvoting your answer.

Comment: But does DIGITS allow you to access this database of numbers? The phone number would be the primary id for each user and each number would have a list of friends (list of friend's numbers) associated with it.

Answer (score 1):

> Technical answer

**Facebook, Twitter and Truecaller** provide free SDKs which you can include in your app to provide phone number based login into your app. What these SDK do is to authenticate an entered phone number (via OTP verification) and nothing more. Hence you can have a phone number OTP verification gateway as soon as user start your app. Using any one of these SDKs, you can know if the phone number verification happened successfully or not. From here on, **you** have the control of the application. **You** will be handling user base. **You** will keep track of user profile, friends, redundancy check (returning user check), etc.

> Business answer

For developing something humongous like a social network, you would want to segregate user ids from the start. You would also want to study more on computer science subjects like Data Structure. Obviously, you can never develop a perfect application. Even if you try doing so upfront, there's a greater chance that new technologies have come up and your perfect solution isn't perfect anymore -- within 2 months. Hence, implement a **feasible solution** first, which is a **perfect tradeoff** between perfection and time remaining for your case and your predictive growth.

> Important links

Phone number OTP verification services:

1. Twitter Fabric Digits: https://get.digits.com/
2. Facebook's OTP verification: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit
3. Truecaller: https://www.truecaller.com/developer